# How to make backups/snapshots in CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

How do I create backups of my entire cluster? Can they only be imported back into CockroachDB or can they also be imported into other systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CockroachDB support generating a snapshot of your entire cluster with the  [`cockroach dump`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/back-up-and-restore-data.html) command. This creates a human-readable output of SQL statements that can be easily imported into other databases, if so desired. Here’s an example of dumping two tables from the same database:

```
cockroach dump db1 tbl1 tbl2 > db1_backup.sql
```

We’re also working on a much more performant, efficient backup-and-restore functionality for our upcoming 1.0 release. The files from the new backup functionality will only be restorable into CockroachDB, however.

Comment: oops, I a dump is generally not seen as a real snapshot. Does crdb support storage snapshots?

Comment: cockroach dump is deprecated in favor of BACKUP and RESTORE as stated here https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/54040

Comment: Just a note the dump command was removed in favour of BACKUP and RESTORE, however you can only use these if you have an enterprise license.

Answer (score 1):

the "more performant efficient backup-and-restore functionality" Alex mentioned has been available for awhile now.  documentation is here:

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/backup.html

Cockroach Labs calls the open source version of the database "Cockroach Core", so open source users should note the caveat at the top of the page:

"Core users can only take full backups. To use the other backup features, you need an enterprise license."

Comment: I could not find convenient way to make backup to local filesystem

Comment: it seems intentional to me....